# Обращение к модулю yii2 в браузере

Tags: php, yii2, модули

Создал в yii2(basic) средствами gii модуль admin:

```
modules/
  admin/
    Module.php                   файл класса модуля
    controllers/                 содержит файлы классов контроллеров
        DefaultController.php    файл класса контроллера по умолчанию
    models/                      содержит файлы классов моделей
    views/                       содержит файлы представлений контроллеров и шаблонов
        layouts/                 содержит файлы представлений шаблонов
        default/                 содержит файлы представления контроллера DefaultController
            index.php            файл основного представления
```

В файле настройки web.php добавил такие строки:

```
   'modules' => [
        'Module' => [
            'class' => 'app\modules\admin\Module',
            'layout' => 'admin',
        ],
    ],
```

Потом пытаюсь обратиться к модулю в браузере: <доменное имя сайта>/admin/
Веб-сервер локальный, Open Server. Доменное имя сайта условно называется yii2shop.
В ответ приходит ошибка 404. Как правильно обратиться к созданному модулю?

Comment: `/admin/default` видимо

Comment: кстати в конфиге в маршрутизации что прописано? может там что-то перекрывает

Comment: не работает /admin/default. Под конфигом маршрутизации понимается файл config/web.php? Если да, то там нет никаких перекрытий нет, кроме настройки 'defaultRoute' => 'category/index', которая подключает дефолтный роут для магазина.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, В том же web.php есть настройка юрлов. Но там все чисто: 'urlManager' => [ 'enablePrettyUrl' => true, 'showScriptName' => false, 'rules' => [ ], ],

Comment: Даже пробую из коробки собрать новый чистый проект, где через gii создаю модуль admin. Прописываю его в настройку config/web.php, потом обращаюсь по адресу http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=admin/default и все так же ошибка 404. Кто знает в чем секрет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему так. В конце файла config/web.php перед return написал следующие строки:

```
$config['modules']['admin'] = [
    'class' => 'app\modules\admin\Module',
    'layout' => 'admin',
];
```

Тогда заработало все. За одно подключил свой слой в свойстве layout.